# Find Dimension of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix with rank $r$, then what is the dimension of the solution space of the system $Ax =0~$?

Comment: any thoughts about the question?

Comment: What do u mean?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't that just the null space?

Comment: @user470523 https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/306553  how to ask a good question. It is good to tell others what you have tried.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply rank-nullity. Let $T(\textbf{x}) = A\textbf{x}$ be the linear map. Since the rank of $A$ is $r$, then by rank-nullity we have $\textbf{dim}(\textrm{im}(T)) + \textbf{dim}(\textrm{ker}(T)) = \textbf{dim}(V)$ i.e $r + k = n \Rightarrow k = n-r.$

Answer (score 2):

Recall the rank-nullity theorem:

> If $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, then
>   $$ \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{nullity}(A) = n,
> $$
>   where $\operatorname{nullity}(A)$ is the dimension of the null space (or kernel) of $A$..

Comment: Oh you beat me to it haha.